# Renormalisation of the fermionic triangle loop

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, fermions, dimensional-regularization

I am trying to renormalise the following loop diagram in the Standard Model:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
[image]

Using the Feynman rules, we can write the amplitude as follows:

$$ \Gamma_f \sim - tr \int  \frac{i}{\displaystyle{\not}\ell -m_f}
\frac{i^2}{(\displaystyle{\not}\ell+ \displaystyle{\not}k -m_f)^2}
\frac{d^4 \ell}{(2 \pi)^4} $$

where $k$ and $\ell$ are external Higgs and loop momenta, and $m_f$ being the fermion mass. I have ignored the coefficients coming from vertex factors.
After evaluating the loop integral functions using dimensional regularisation, I ended up with the following expression:

$$  \Gamma_f \sim \frac{m_f}{4 \pi^2}
\left( 3\Delta -6\ln \frac{m_f}{\mu} +4 
-6 \sqrt{1-4x} \ \ln \frac{1 +\sqrt{1-4x}}{2\sqrt{x}} \right).$$

The loop integral is clearly divergent due to
$\Delta \equiv \ln \pi  - \gamma_E + 2/\epsilon$
term, when
$\epsilon = 4 -d \to 0$.
Here, $x \equiv (m_f/k)^2$,  $d$ is dimension, $\mu$ regularisation scale, and $\gamma_E$ being Euler-Mascheroni constant.

How should I introduce the counter-terms to make the expression for the amplitude finite?

Comment: If I'm being correct, you can simply add a new fundamental interaction $\mathcal L\sim g_\text{new}Zhh$, with this you can renormalize this new coupling and add a counter-term for the UV divergence of your result. I think there's nothing wrong with doing this, these are renormalized parameters and not adding this interaction would correspond to set the running coupling $g_\text{new}(Q)=0$ at any scale $Q$, making irrelevant your result.